# Is it appropriate to ask a question regarding how and which software I would need to use to perform a specific task?

Tags: discussion, allowed-questions

I am curious as to whether I would be downvoted for asking the following question:

> What software(s) would I need and how would I have to use them to create a box plot for data for which I only know the 95% confidence interval and mean?

If this is not the best place to ask this question could you please direct me to a free Q&A site, preferably a stackexchange one, where I could ask the question and expect to actually get an answer in the next few days?

Comment: For statistics related questions, Cross Validated (also known as stats.SE) is better suited. I don't know how they take software related questions, though.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

To not leave this unanswered, I quote the responses on  [Stats meta](https://stats.meta.stackexchange.com/q/1680):

> not only is this fine, I wish others would phrase their questions like it. All too often people instead ask perfectly general and interesting questions in the restricted form of "how can I do this in R/SAS/Stata/Whatever," which is limiting and repetitive. -- whuber ♦
>
> "Make sure your question is related to **statistics**, **machine learning**, or **data analysis** and is not solely about programming, support, or bugs. Include additional tags referring to the statistical issues involved." -- Andre Silva

Subsequently, the question was [well received](https://stats.stackexchange.com/q/64880) on Stats main site.

---

Remark. About 30% of questions tagged [statistics](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/statistics) on Math remain unanswered, one of the
[highest unanswered rates among tags](http://chat.stackexchange.com/transcript/message/10348774#10348774). Something to consider when deciding whether to post on Math or Stats.